# Loading static files in django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I'm just at my wits end here. I want to load my custom js files from the static folder.
When I view the source on Chrome, it's not showing up and it's not being loaded when I refresh the page.

What it looks like on Chrome (and I can't click on my file, while the jQuery does light up):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<script src="/static/js/ajax.js"/>
```

**UPDATE**:
Here is what I have now, but it's still not working

base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"/>
<script src="{% static 'js/ajax.js' %}"/>
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
STATIC_URL = 'assets/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

I ran `python manage.py collectstatic` and it copied a bunch of files over.

Here is a layout of the updated structure. You can see that the ajax.js was copied over but it's still not showing up when I run the server. Any ideas?

[image]

What am I missing?? Please help.
Python 2.7, Django 1.7

Comment: Can you post your view?

Comment: looks like a lot of double quotes. maybe mix it up like this: `<script src="{% static 'bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: also usually you put your static files in a folder called something like `assets` and add that to `STATICFILES_DIRS`, you also have to make sure that `STATIC_URL` is set to `/static/` and that `STATIC_ROOT` is set to the path from which to serve static files, usu. `"static"`, then call `python manage.py collectstatic`. [Static files how-to docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/) are pretty good.

Comment: are you using Apache? you will also need to create an alias for `/static/` and make sure that you `Require all granted`

Comment: see my 2nd comment - `STATICFILES_DIR` is **not** where your files are served from, but where they are _copied_ from when you call `collectstatic` so you should **not** set this to `"static"`. Instead set `STATIC_ROOT` to `"static"`.

Comment: @MarkMikofski I'm using the development server right now but I plan to deploy to pythonanywhere when I'm ready. So your suggestion is to put the actual served files in a folder called `assets`, change `STATIC_ROOT = /assets/`, then call `python manage.py collectstatic`. Am I getting that right?

Comment: @MarkMikofski, see my edits, I think I got what you were saying, but for some reason it's still not showing up

Comment: Are you talking about the files not showing up for Django `runserver` (where you don't need to call `collectstatic`), or only on production using another server?

Comment: Set `STATIC_URL='/static/'` and `STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'static')`, move your files to `assets/` then execute `python manage.py collectstatic` I think you are also missing `os.path.join` on `STATCFILES_DIR`

Comment: @Kos they are not showing up when  call `runserver`

Comment: @MarkMikofski I tried that, still no luck. I really don't know what I'm missing. Here's what I have: `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),)`

Comment: Open your page in Chrome, then right click select inspect element, look for what django renders for your static link, then you can figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory reading:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#static-files

---

About these settings:

```
STATIC_URL = 'assets/'
```

This means that your app should serve static files with `assets/{name}` prefix.

**I think this is the source of your problem** - the initial `/` is missing and you're generating relative links for static resources, which sounds like a Bad Idea.

Now a page at `http://yourserver/foo/bar/` would ask for static files via a relative link:
`<img src="assets/{name}">`, so your browser would look in `/foo/bar/assets/{name}` and find nothing.
You'd normally want an absolute link for static files, so instead you should use `STATIC_URL = '/assets/'` and obtain absolute links `<img src="/assets/{name}">`.

---

```
STATICFILES_DIRS=(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

Okay, so how does Django find the static files? A Django project can have many installed applications, and each application can have its own directory with static files.

So there's this setting (set by default):

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder")
```

This means that, on development setup (`runserver`), whenever someone asks for `http://yourserver/assets/ponies/applejack.jpg` (where `/assets/` is your, now hopefully fixed, `STATIC_URL`), Django would try to find a file `ponies/applejack.jpg` in the following way:

- first by using `FileSystemFinder` that looks in some fixed directories you specify (`STATICFILES_DIRS`),
- second by using `AppDirectoriesFinder` that looks into the `static/` subdirectory of each of your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

So if you want to keep your static files per-app, you don't need to rely on `FileSystemFinder` and you can leave `STATICFILES_DIRS` empty.

But if you want to keep all the static files in one place, point `STATICFILES_DIRS` to any directory like you did. You should still keep `AppDirectoriesFinder` for third party apps you use, like the Django Admin, that come with their own static files.

---

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
```

This is unnecessary for development setup with `runserver` because Django dev server serves your static files itself.

For production, however, you probably want your web server (Apache, Nginx, ...) or a content delivery network to handle the static file delivery for you. You can then use the `collectstatic` command to collect all the static files from everywhere (e.g. all static files your `STATICFILES_FINDERS` can find), and put them all in one directory on your machine, from where you can easily pass them on to Nginx or copy over to a CDN.

Comment: This is a great walkthrough for using static files. I just got it to work. The issue seemed to be using bootstrap3-django plugin. The template tags were messing with my other static file declarations. I ended up getting rid of it and manually including the bootstrap files. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this in your settings?

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    # django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```